# Add Reply To email header in Mailjet API

Tags: c#, api, email, mailjet

How do I add the Reply To email header in Mailjet API? Or other headers?

Google search reveals the property `ReplyEmail` but that is only for `Newsletter.Resource` and not for `Send.Resource`.

Answer (score 4):

Using MailJet V3 API:

```
MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient("MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC", "MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE");
         MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
         {
            Resource = Send.Resource,
         }
            .Property(Send.FromEmail, "pilot@mailjet.com")
            .Property(Send.FromName, "Mailjet Pilot")
            .Property(Send.Subject, "Your email flight plan!")
            .Property(Send.TextPart, "Dear passenger, welcome to Mailjet!")
            .Property(Send.HtmlPart, "<h3>Dear passenger, welcome to Mailjet!</h3>")
            .Property(Send.Recipients, new JArray {
                new JObject {
                 {"Email", "passenger@mailjet.com"}
                 }
                })
            .Property(Send.Headers, new JObject {
                {"Reply-To", "copilot@mailjet.com"}
                });
         MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```

Using the Send.Headers, from this link: https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#adding-email-headers-v3
    And slightly different for V3.1: https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#send-api-v3-to-v3-1

To save people time: if you are getting 200 success status code but no emails, check your allowed senders list. Also "Bcc" doesn't work with "Recipients", "Bcc" should be used with the "To" field.

Answer (score 2):

Sending email with Reply-to using the MailJet PHP library:

```
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client('xxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxx',true,['version' => 'v3.1']);
$body = [
'Messages' => [
  [
    'From' => [
      'Email' => "",
      'Name' => ""
    ],
    'To' => [
      [
        'Email' => "", 
        'Name' => ""
      ]
    ],
    'Subject' => "", 
    'TextPart' => "", 
    'HTMLPart' => "", 
    'Headers' => [
      'Reply-To' => ""
    ]                           
  ]
 ]
];

$response = $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $body]);
$response->success();
```